# gomobile compatibility

Tags: go, gomobile

I'm writing some test apps with gomobile and native golang. Strangely the apps don't run on Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.1 but work on Galaxy Note 5 with Android 5.1.1. Does anyone know the clear hardware and software requirements for current version of gomobile? I don't think it's in any of the documents or speeches.

Comment: I can install the apk file, but when I run it on S3 it quits running in about 1 second. Have you run gomobile apps successfully on S3 before? If yes then may I know the software version you have? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to install a Hello world application on the same hardware? Just to make sure the problem is with golang in general or with some of its API

Answer (score 1):

The only hardware compatibility note I can find for Go Mobile is [this one](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Mobile#building-and-deploying-to-android-1) which states:

> Note: Go Mobile runs on the same architectures as Go, which currently means ARM, ARM64, 386 and amd64 devices and emulators. Notably, Android on MIPS devices is not yet supported.